# Google charts annotations lineWidth not changing

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

I have a Google LineChart with two annotations and I need to change the width of the annotation lines.

According to the [LineChart documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) the property lineWidth should work as in the following:

```
series: {
    0: {
        annotations: {
            textStyle: {fontSize: 12, color: 'red' },
            lineWidth: 5
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot make this work properly, here there is a [JFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/046ytmeb/) where apparently the properties lineWidth, color and visibleInLegend have no effect on the chart.

I'm interested in particular in editing the width and color of the first two  vertical lines ("foo" and "bar") which are not related to any series.